# Hash Table reinserting after increasing in size

Tags: c++, hashtable

I've been working on this hash table implementation and I've hit a roadblock. I modified the constructor and insert functions to be able to resize the array if capacity is reached, but I'm having problems with the resize. Right now, it seems to be infinitely inserting negative data and I'm not sure why. Should I implement an iterator within the resize or is there a simpler way of doing it?

Here are the functions:

resize:

```
template <class RecordType>
void table<RecordType>::resize( )
{

    RecordType *oldData = data;
    int oldSize = CAPACITY;
    int newSize = CAPACITY *2;

    //create a new table
    RecordType *newData;
    newData = new RecordType[CAPACITY];

    size_t i;
    used = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
        newData[i].key = NEVER_USED;

    data = newData;
    delete[] newData;

    //place data from old table to new, larger table.
    for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++)
    {
            RecordType next = oldData[i];
            insert(next);
    }

    CAPACITY = newSize;
    delete[] oldData;
}
```

constructor:

```
template <class RecordType>
table<RecordType>::table( )
{
    CAPACITY = 30;
    data = new RecordType[CAPACITY];

    size_t i;

    used = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
        data[i].key = NEVER_USED;

}
```

insert:

```
template <class RecordType>
void table<RecordType>::insert(const RecordType& entry)
// Library facilities used: cassert
{
    bool already_present;   // True if entry.key is already in the table
    size_t index;        // data[index] is location for the new entry

    assert(entry.key >= 0);

    // Set index so that data[index] is the spot to place the new entry.
    find_index(entry.key, already_present, index);

    // If the key wasn't already there, then find the location for the new entry.
    if (!already_present)
    {
        if (size( ) >= CAPACITY)
        {
            resize( ); // resize the table.

            insert(entry); // reinsert entry into new table.
        }
        else if (size( ) < CAPACITY)
        {
            index = hash(entry.key);

            while (!is_vacant(index))
                index = next_index(index);
            ++used;
        }
    }

    data[index] = entry;
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<CAPACITY; i++) cout << data[i].key << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `resize()` is calling `insert()` which is putting data into the `data[]`. Then `resize()` overwrites `data` with the empty (full of `NEVER_USED`) `newData` array. My guess is that you want to get rid of `newData` and just use `data` instead.

You probably should rethink `CAPACITY *= CAPACITY` as well, as this is going to blow up when you try to use this code for something real.

Comment: Ok so I changed the resize() to delete the newData before inserting the oldData into the now-larger data. But instead of infinitely adding numbers, it just freezes after trying to add 1 more value than the newSize (also changed CAPACITY *= CAPACITY). Is the reinsert loop doing the right thing?